# How to bulk delete by keys with python and appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is the next solution will work good in case of 10000+ items ?

```
q = db.GqlQuery('SELECT __key__ FROM Event where date_create < [DATE(2012, 1, 23)]')
db.delete(q)
```

What is the right solution to bulk delete ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py#1613), the datastore module will batch multiple delete RPCs if the number of keys is > `MAX_DELETE_KEYS` (500).

You should do this in a task queue as it might take more than 60s, and will trigger a `DeadlineExceededException`.

Comment: So the GAE will only batch deletes for keys more than 500?

Comment: Nop, the datastore module should batch your delete in a single RPC if < 500.